# NVIDIA GPU slows down unexpectidely

Tags: gpu, rendering, nvidia

We have an application taking data from a camera and processing it in real time through the gpu to render a scene.  The gpu is an Nvidia RTX 3000 in a Lenovo laptop T15.

Our application is started and all goes well for a first session of rendering, FPS is tracking at 30, gpu power is at 70W, cpu is around 50%.  One application session lasts for a few minutes and results are fully rendered in real time.

Then we initiate a second application session and the FPS plummets and rendering lags which is unacceptable for our application (in the health space).  Power drops to 30W and the gpu appears to not be loaded at all neither is the cpu.

We tried moving part of the initialization code to when we detect the beginning of the session, it works better and let us handle a few sessions in a row, but eventually the behavior reappears after a while.

Temperature does not seem to be involved here so we do not think the gpu gets throttled for excess temperature.

any suggestion on where to look for and how to get a more deterministic behavior ?  Anything specific we could reset between sessions?

thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score -1):

There could be several reasons why your NVIDIA GPU is slowing down unexpectedly. Here are some possible causes:

Overheating: If your GPU is not being properly cooled, it can overheat and slow down to prevent damage to the hardware.

Driver Issues: Outdated or corrupt drivers can cause performance issues with your GPU. Make sure you have the latest drivers installed for your specific GPU model.

Hardware Issues: A faulty GPU can also cause slowdowns or crashes. Check for any physical damage or defects on the GPU, and consider getting it repaired or replaced if necessary.

Power Issues: Insufficient power supply can also cause performance issues with your GPU. Make sure your power supply is adequate for your GPU's power requirements.

Background Processes: Too many background processes or applications running on your computer can also impact GPU performance. Close any unnecessary applications or processes to free up resources.

Settings: Make sure your GPU settings are optimized for performance. Adjusting settings such as resolution, anti-aliasing, and texture quality can help improve performance.

It's recommended to troubleshoot and identify the specific cause of the issue before attempting any fixes. If you're unsure how to proceed, seek assistance from a qualified technician or customer support.

For more info like this. checkout [How to reset a Lenovo laptop?](https://www.gadgetcatcher.com/how-to-reset-a-lenovo-laptop/)

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).